# A sect call Muslims outsiders "Wahhabi". Allowed?

Tags: muslim-practices, bidah

An Indo-Pak Sufi sect call Muslims outside their group Wahhabis because of Muhammad ibn Abd al-Wahhab as he called many of their practices innovations with no basis on Qur'an and Sunnah. Any Muslim who disagrees with them is called Wahhabi in a negative way even if they follow the above scholar or not. More seriously Al-Wahhab is a name of Allah so to use it negatively is mocking Allah. So should they use such a term? They also use the word wobbler in a similar context.

A scholar of theirs replies to a question about calling them (outsiders) wobblers: https://youtube.com/watch?v=QugxYKxTlZY and https://youtube.com/watch?v=9DHyJg6sLNs.

Comment: A scholar of theirs replies to a question about calling them (outsiders) wobblers: https://youtube.com/watch?v=QugxYKxTlZY

Comment: I've edited your post adding that comment.

Comment: You can [edit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/45820/edit) your original question to add additional information.

Comment: I listened to both videos and it is not clear to me which Wahhabis he is referring to: followers of Mohammad ibn Abdul-Wahhab or followers of Abdul-Wahhab ibn Rustum. The people asking the questions mentioned that those people called themselves Wahhabis. Followers of Mohammad ibn Abdul-Wahhab neither call themselves Wahhabis nor Salafis; this is a term that the media uses to describe them. Which group of Wahhabis is your question about?

Comment: **Registered users can comment on and edit their own posts. Unregistered users can't. If you are unwilling or unable to register your account to gain these privileges, posting new "answers" instead just wastes everyone's time and is not an appropriate alternative.**

Answer (score 2):

Shortly this is a kind of backbiting or gheeba (for more details read [Is there a hadd punishment for gheebah/backbiting? Please Answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45716/is-there-a-hadd-punishment-for-gheebah-backbiting-please-answer/45731#45731)) or mockery.

Allah the almighty says:

> O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people; perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule [other] women; perhaps they may be better than them. **And do not insult one another and do not call each other by** [offensive] **nicknames**. **Wretched is the name of disobedience after** [one's] **faith**. And whoever does not repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers. ([49:11](http://legacy.quran.com/49/11))

It is a sinful act to call other Muslims whom apparently follow the orders of Allah or believers by nicknames they might hate or dislike no matter if this may apply for them or not (also read [here in qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1754&Itemid=105) an interpretation of the verse based on a summary of tafsir ibn Kathir).

Note that there's no connection  between al-Wahhab the supposed name of Allah and the nickname "wahhabi".

For further information you should read the verse above in more context (for example [49:9-17](http://legacy.quran.com/49/9-17)).

**Side note on "Wahhabi": meaning and history**

Note that if one wanted to refer to a follower of [Muhammad ibn 'Abdulwahhab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_ibn_Abd_al-Wahhab) correctly than calling him "Wahhabi" in Arabic is wrong, as Abdulwahhab (the father of the Scholar) has nothing to do with the movement of his son, a more correct reference would be calling him "Muhammadi".
Historically the first whom were called "Wahhabi" where the followers of [Abdul-Wahhab ibn Rustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_al-Wahhab_ibn_Rustam) the leader and founder of the first Ibadi Dynasty in what we now call Algeria and Tunisia.