# What is considered 'insulting a Muslim'? And is it a sin? If so, is it a minor or major scene?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

Assalamu 'Alaikum,

My question is kinda lengthy here. So, the important question is regarding a situation.

So, there was this guy who bought a wrong book, since it had the same name but the book had a different number on it. Everybody was laughing, not as insult though, just because the situation was funny when he realised he was doing the wrong sums from the wrong book. So, when everybody was commenting on it, someone said, obviously as a joke, "can't you read numbers?" and laughed it off. The guy who bought the wrong book obviously didn't mind and now, he probably doesn't even remember about that remark since everybody was talking. Now, it is not even a valid insult because it has nothing to do with him not being able to read numbers. He didn't specify the book number and that's how he got the wrong book.

The insult is kinda like jokingly calling Albert Einstein stupid because he forgot his pen or something. And the person who "insulted" the guy didn't mean it as an insult at all. In fact, she didn't even know insulting someone was a sin, but she was getting bad vibes about that action but wasn't completely sure and then researched it, and she found out it might be a sin.

**Now my question is**: " Is it a sin in this case?"

It would be great if you could quote hadiths and passages from Quran where it says it's a major or minor sin. But my main question is regarding the situation above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in Islam the topic of insulating is wide spread, so it may have some intersetcions with ghaybah, namimah or cursing etc.

One could say anything said or done by another person to make a Muslim get angry or feel angry or ashamed, abused or more general bad might fall under this definition.

Allah the Almighty said:

> O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people; perhaps they may be better than them; nor let women ridicule [other] women; perhaps they may be better than them. **And do not insult one another and do not call each other by [offensive] nicknames**. Wretched is the name of disobedience after [one's] faith. And whoever does not repent - then it is those who are the wrongdoers. ([49:11](https://legacy.quran.com/49/11))

Note that what ever might cause a Muslim harm might be a reason to apply ta'azir for a judge as it is a sinful act and considered as haram. Based on the Qur'an:

> And those who harm believing men and believing women for [something] other than what they have earned have certainly born upon themselves a slander and manifest sin. ([33:58](https://legacy.quran.com/33/58))

That's why the best Muslim is that who is described in the hadith:

> Verily a person asked the Messenger of Allah (may peace and blessings be upon him) who amongst the Muslims was better. Upon this (the Holy Prophet) remarked: From whose hand and tongue the Muslims are safe. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/68))

Based on your description of the situation one might come to the conclusion that that person didn't feel harmed by any means and took it as something funny which might happen to anyone of us. This leads to the conclusion that it doesn't fall under insulting, but it would be nevertheless good to repent in similar cases, as one never knows how a person might react in such a situation.

That's why our messenger () warned us from standing or staying at the paths, as it might lead us to do things that may harm others:

> Avoid sitting on the paths. They (the Companions) said: Allah's Messenger, we cannot help but holding our meetings (in these paths) and discuss matters (there). Thereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: If you insist on holding meetings, then give the path its due right. They said: What are its due rights? Upon this he said: Lowering the gaze, refraining from doing harm, exchanging of greetings. commanding of good and forbidding from evil. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/26) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/3))

See also [Is there a hadd punishment for gheebah/backbiting? Please Answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45716/is-there-a-hadd-punishment-for-gheebah-backbiting-please-answer)
[Should we speak about someone (when he is bad, and I'm sure about that) to aware others?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33665/should-we-speak-about-someone-when-he-is-bad-and-im-sure-about-that-to-aware)

Read also in this hadith in [sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/45/40) on the prohibition of wrongdoing a Muslim.

Finally note that cursing other is considered among the major sins as you may find it in imam a-Dhahabis [book](http://www.islamtomorrow.com/books/major_sins/majorSins.pdf) on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons that one shouldn't execute this action.

First of all there are the following ayats in the Quran that gives a very good argument as to why you shouldn't even make fun of another Muslim (i.e. a Muslim who you know takes Islam very seriously)

> *“Allah is the guardian of those who believe.”* 
>   **Surah al-Baqarah 2: 257**
>
> *“That is because Allah is the Protector of those who believe.”* **Surah Muhammad 47: 11**

These two ayats clearly show that Allah will protect those who believe. So for those who make fun of eachother they are committing a transgression (not a sin) which still is higly discouraged.

> “They who taunt those of the faithful who give their alms freely, and those who give to the extent of their earnings and scoff at them; Allah will pay them back their scoffings and they shall have a painful chastisement.” 
>   **Surah at-Tawba 9: 79**

One should never how small it may be make fun of someone else. It might be fine in the beginning but as days pass by one might think it's ok to scoff that person. Then this will result in a conflict. 
Maybe you should ask that person if he was fine it. But make sure next time you only laugh if he laughs honestly about his own mistake.

As the final part of the answer making fun of someone becomes a sin if you see the victim being humiliated against his will. Then you should stop.

> The forty-third sin promised Divine Chastisement is insulting a believer, degrading him, defaming him, abusing or taunting him. Insulting a believer in any manner is Harām whether it is in jest or by way of abuse or criticism, or in relation with his defects; or by scolding or reprimanding him or considering him lowly and debasing him, denouncing him, taunting him or hurting his feelings in any way.

Source:

https://www.al-islam.org/greater-sins-volume-3-ayatullah-sayyid-abdul-husayn-dastghaib-shirazi/forty-third-greater-sin#block-search-form

Comment: You're welcome. Fi aminillah.